# Firefox 17.0.1 not receiving http response

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, servlets, httpresponse

I'm developing a website that makes classic ajax request with jQuery 1.8.0 to a Java servlet (a Struts 1 action, precisely). I should receive json, which is created with Jackson.

Most of the time, everything is normal, but from times to times, Firefox 17 seems not to receive the response and hangs until I end its process with Windows' task manager. I can see in Firebug that the request has been sent, and in OC4J's logs that my servet has been called and the response sent, but no reponse is received. Even with a timeout, the jQuery ajax error method is never called and Firefox stays completely blocked.

I tried restart Firefox with addons disabled, but still the same problem.

The weirdest is that this problem doesn't occur, neither with IE, neither with Chrome.

I won't post any code unless asked to, because my code is quite classic.

Do any of you has already faced this issue? Or maybe has a clue about it?

Thanks.

EDIT

My code is asynchronous, so Firefox shouldn't be hanging like this, I don't get it.

Code, as asked:

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'calculate.do?action=career',
    timeout: 40000,
    data : {
    "data": JSON.stringify(obj)
    },
    success: function(json){
        // do stuff with json, like setting some field's values
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        // error message somewhere in the page
    }
);
```

Struts action:

```
    private static final String A_JSON_STRING = "{\"msg\" : \"success\", "
         + "\"code\" : \"0\"}";

    public ActionForward career(final ActionMapping mapping,
        final ActionForm form, final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        PrintWriter writer = null;
        writer = response.getWriter();
        String json = request.getParameter("data");

        // do stuff with json then send a response 

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        writer.write(A_JSON_STRING);

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        // struts should return an action forward but as it's an ajax call,
        // there's no need to
        return null;

}
```

I'm skipping the try/catch/finally for clarity, but it's present in my code.

**EDIT 2:** I ended up switching to Firefox 18 (beta) and everyting seems to be ok now...

Comment: Your code "is quite classic"? Post it please. Are you using a synchronous request?

Comment: What exactly is "classic" code? Do you use a serif font?